# Youtube API, disallowing controls except for the sound control?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Would there be a way to, using the Youtube API, only show the volume control? Much like setting "controls=0", except keeping the volume button.

Comment: It doesn't look like YT would support such thing: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#controls They have their branding that they want to keep, and those controls are the minimum.

Comment: I don't mean hide completely everything. I mean hide what the usual "control=0" hides, except keep the volume button there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to automatically hiding YouTube controls, [Supported Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters) in YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters states that supported values to autohide for **AS3** player are as follows:

> - 2 (default) – If the player has a 16:9 or 4:3 aspect ratio, the video progress bar and player controls display or hide automatically. Otherwise, those controls are visible throughout the video.
> - 1 – Regardless of the player's dimensions, the video progress bar and player controls display or hide automatically.
> - 0 – Regardless of the player's dimensions, the video progress bar and player controls are visible throughout the video.

And to display controls for **HTML5 or AS3**, you may use controls with the following values:

> - controls=0 – Player controls do not display in the player. For IFrame embeds, the Flash player loads immediately.
> - controls=1 (default) – Player controls display in the player. For IFrame embeds, the controls display immediately and the Flash player also loads immediately.
> - controls=2 – Player controls display in the player. For IFrame embeds, the controls display and the Flash player loads after the user initiates the video playback.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API does not control the video player.

All player parameters can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters).